# Attachments with article in joomla 1.6

Tags: attachment, article, joomla1.6

I'm using joomla 1.6 to develop a website also i'm beginner to joomla. I need to attach one or more pdf files with the article. Any one can please help me to attach file with article and how to get this attachment in frontend. Please help any one how to do that. I tried with phoco download and attachments plugin. But i don't

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to log into administration and edit your article in Content Items Manager. With the editor you can insert a link. When you do, click on Shared Documents and then upload the pdf you want to attach.

Answer (score 0):

In your article, you need to use your insert/edit link, in the Link URL section enter the full link of where the pdf is found e.g. www.yourdomainname/images/myfile.pdf. It is always advised to open the pdf in a new window so you can set that in the insert/edit link. Hope this helps.